# Can I merge-sort two sorted files by using comm?

Tags: sort, coreutils, comm

[comm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) assumes its two inputs are sorted. Is it correct that it works in the same way as the merge sort algorithm?
If yes, can I use [comm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) to merge-sort two sorted files?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd just `sort -mu file1 file2`.

Answer (score 2):

`comm` acts like a single merge step of the merge sort algorithm, and further, produces separated output (in different columns), not combined output. Therefore it can't be used to "merge-sort" anything.